# What is the best approach to HttpWatch automation with C#?

Tags: c#, httpwatch

We decided to automate manual Httpwatch pro testing. Basically we are going to create a tool that will run in the background while the manual testers do their testing going through our website and the tool will check the tags and values. What is the best approach for this? it looks like we need something like this:

```
if title of page is x

  if tag is y 

    if value is z then pass else fail.
```

Looks like x, y and z should be hardcoded (or put into database or flat file manually beforehand). Is there something I am missing? what is your approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For the front-end part where you intend to use manual testers, you can use [Testing Anywhere](http://www.automationanywhere.com/Testing/products/automated-testing-anywhere.htm) to automate the process with functionalities like [creating test exes](http://www.automationanywhere.com/Testing/products/test-to-exe.htm) that will allow you to create multiple concurrent sessions on the web application. This will allow you to measure the performance in an automated scenario for multiple number of users.

Answer (score 0):

Is using Httpwatch important for your project?
If you are familiar with C#, C++ or Java, then you can do this with HTTP Debugger API.

[HTTP Debugger API](http://www.httpdebugger.com/manual/httpdebugger_api.html)

```
static void api_OnRequestHeader(uint id, string userName, string appName, bool isClient,string ipAddr,string url, string header)
{
    1. get tags from header
    2. check url and tags
}
```